# can you help me with these sql problem?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

hi i am using phpmyadmin 3.3.9 . i have a sql prblem in which i dont know what is the problem at all..

heres the code looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE metars(
metar varchar( 255 ) NOT NULL default '',
timestamp timestamp( 14 ) NOT NULL ,
station varchar( 4 ) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( station ) ,
UNIQUE KEY station( station )
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

and heres the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( 14 ) NOT NULL , station varchar( 4 ) NOT NULL default '', PRIMARY KE' at line 3
```

Comment: It's not good to use `timestamp` for a field name.

Comment: According to the error message, you also have a `default ''` at the end of your `station` line.  Are you sure that's your exact input?

Comment: And since you have `station` as the Primary Key, you don't need another `UNIQUE` constraint on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with `timestamp timestamp NOT NULL ,`
There's no length/format option for timestamp (that is: not for mysql 5.1, see ypercube's comment)

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

```
data_type:
    BIT[(length)]
  | TINYINT[(length)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
  | SMALLINT[(length)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
  | MEDIUMINT[(length)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
  | INT[(length)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
  | INTEGER[(length)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
  | BIGINT[(length)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
  | REAL[(length,decimals)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
  | DOUBLE[(length,decimals)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
  | FLOAT[(length,decimals)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
  | DECIMAL[(length[,decimals])] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
  | NUMERIC[(length[,decimals])] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
  | DATE
  | TIME
  | TIMESTAMP
  | DATETIME
  | YEAR
  | CHAR[(length)]
 [...]
```

But I'd avoid using keywords and/or type names as identifiers.

Comment: Actually there was an option for TIMESTAMP length/format. MySQL 5.0.51 creates the table but shows this warning when the OP's code is run: **`'TIMESTAMP(14)' is deprecated; use 'TIMESTAMP' instead`**

Answer (score 3):

'timestamp' is a keyword of MySQL. Thus, change the column name 'timestamp' to other or wrap it by grave(`). And you don't have to set the column length of timestamp type.

And PRIMARY KEY also means uniqueness. So, UNIQUE KEY station ( station ) is not necessary here.

```
CREATE TABLE metars(
metar varchar( 255 ) NOT NULL default '',
`timestamp` timestamp,
station varchar( 4 ) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( station )
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE metars(
`metar` varchar( 255 ) NOT NULL default '',
`timestamp` timestamp( 14 ) NOT NULL ,
`station` varchar( 4 ) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( `station` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY station( `station` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

this one should be good